# How to join two different queryset in one dict

Tags: python, django

I have the result of two querysets and I need to put it together to iterate on my view.

```
data = dict()
item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=pk)
phase = item.phase_set.all()
evaluation = item.evaluation_set.all().exists()
data["timeline"] = phase
....
return render(request, 'item_detail.html', data)
```

I need to put in `data["timeline"]` the value of `phase` and the value of `evaluation`, how can I add the `evaluation` result in `phase` result?

`evaluation` receive `true` or `false`, in my view  I need to show the phase values if `evaluation` is true

Model phase

```
class Phase_History(models.Model):  # noqa
    date_change = models.DateTimeField('date')
    item = models.ForeignKey('Item', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    author = models.ForeignKey('users.UserProfile', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    current = models.BooleanField()
```

Model Evaluation

```
class Evaluation(models.Model):
    valuator = models.ForeignKey('users.UserProfile', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    item = models.ForeignKey('Idea', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

In my item_detail.html view:

```
{% for timeline_item in timeline %}
  {% if evaluation %}
    {{timeline_item.date_change}}
    {{timeline_item.author}}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
....
```

Comment: `phase` is a queryset of many objects, but `evaluation` is a single value `True/False`. So it's not clear what you mean by putting `evaluation` inside `timeline`. Your question might be clearer if you showed your models and showed what you want to write for `...` in the template.

Comment: @Alasdair I edited to add more details. I hope that is clear. As I said, I want to show the values of phase if the evaluation is true.

Comment: You can add `evaluation` to the context dict with `data["evaluation"] = evaluation`. Note that for the example template, `evaluation` is the same for every loop, therefore you could move the `{% if evaluation %}` outside of the loop so that you only check it once.

Comment: I got it. But the `evaluation` value is different according to the item.

Comment: *But the evaluation value is different according to the item* - it isn't at the moment. You have `evaluation = item.evaluation_set.all().exists()`, so the result only depends on the `item`, not on the `phase`.

Comment: I'm gonna follow your tips and implements like you said above.